# Can an enol acetate be formed through Fischer esterification?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, esters

Since acetone is converted into its enol form under acidic conditions, could it participate in Fischer esterification to form an enol acetate? For example, would refluxing acetone, p-TSA, and acetic acid form the unsaturated ester?

[image: Reaction scheme]

Comment: My suspicion is no, although apparently you can transesterify by refluxing acetone with TsOH + allyl acetate ([*JOC* **2012,** *77,* 10347](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo301984p))